# Why functions.php file is called 8 time for just one page load?

Tags: functions

I just added following code to functions.php.

```
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Test Title 02',
  'post_content'  => 'Test Des 02',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1
);

wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

There are 8 posts were created just one page load. Seems like functions.php file is called 8 time for just one page load. Why is that? How it happens?

Comment: how you checked that 8 posts were added? from WordPress Dashboard?

Answer (score 4):

Add a plugin like [`Kint Debugger`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/kint-debugger/) + [`Debug Bar`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/) and add the following code to your `functions.php`.

```
    global $wp;
    ob_start('kint_debug_ob');
    d($wp);
    ob_end_flush();
```

When you check the Debug Bar you should see the backtrace which will tell you which order functions were fired in. Loading 8 times is quite high for a single request.

There is also a backtrace function you can use that is less detailed if you don't want to go the plugin route - [`wp_debug_backtrace_summary`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_debug_backtrace_summary/).

```
echo "<!----- BACKTRACE / START ----->";

print_r ( wp_debug_backtrace_summary() );

echo "<!----- BACKTRACE / END ----->";
```

It is a bit odd to just have a random [`wp_insert_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) in your `functions.php` so perhaps wrapping your logic in a hook like [`init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) could help in the mean time.

There is also a possibility this is not just a single request. [`heartbeats`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_heartbeat_settings) will ping the backend if you're in the admin section and It's possible [`wp-cron`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cron) can trigger it to load as well (but I'm not sure).

To double check it all, enable [`WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) and log the events.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** - ALWAYS PUT commands in actions:

```
add_action('init', 'my_func');
function my_func(){
    //.......
    //.......
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );
}
```

also, to avoid repeated inclusion, put this code in top of .php file:

```
if (defined('my_wpse_9999')) || !define('my_wpse_9999',true)) return;
```